# Using @AppStorage for string map

Tags: swiftui, nsuserdefaults, ios14

How can I use `@AppStorage` for a string map in a SwiftUI app?

This is what I want to do:

```
@AppStorage("ratings") var ratings: [String: Double] = []
```

But this gives me the error message “No exact matches in call to initializer”. When looking at the documentation, it looks like only a few data types are supported. It is possible to encode it as `Data`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage) for `@AppStorage` the only values that you can currently store using this property wrapper are

- `Int`
- `Double`
- `String`
- `Bool`
- `URL`
- `Data`

And their optional counterparts. You can also store values that conform to `RawRepresentable`, like enums that conform to `Int` or `String`.

If you want to store a dictionary using this method then you would have to convert it to data and store it that way.

```
@AppStorage("ratings")
var ratings: Data = Data() // we need to initialize it with something
```

Then we can save to it using

```
let data = ["Hello": 5.0]
guard let ratings = try? JSONEncoder().encode(data) else { return }
self.ratings = ratings
```

And if we want to retrieve it we can do the following:

```
guard let decodedRatings = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:Double].self, from: ratings) else { return }
print(decodedRatings)
```

Otherwise you will have to use UserDefaults directly, you can always use `onChange` and State to manage it. See this [example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-some-code-when-state-changes-using-onchange) of how to use `onChange`. You may need to create a custom init for your view so as to populate the State the value from UserDefaults.

Though you could write your own property wrapper, this [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/) by John Sundell explains in detail how to do it.

Comment: That was a lot to process. Thank you so much for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this array extension to use structs in AppStorage, just add this to your code above ContentView:

```
extension Array: RawRepresentable where Element: Codable {
public init?(rawValue: String) {
    guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
          let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
    else {
        return nil
    }
    self = result
}

public var rawValue: String {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
          let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    else {
        return "[]"
    }
    return result                                                        
    }
}
```

And then you can create a struct for your data type:

```
struct Rating: Hashable, Codable {
var howManyStars: Int
var notes: String
}
```

Then make your AppStorage array like this:

```
@AppStorage("rating") var ratings: [Rating] = []
```

I hope this helps.