# 'No exact matches in call to initializer' error on @AppStorage variable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm getting the following error: `No exact matches in call to initializer` on my [@AppStorage](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-appstorage-property-wrapper) variable below:

**Model.swift**

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("minAge") var minAge: Float = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "minAge")
```

This variable is meant to bind to a `Slider` value below.

**Settings.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
struct Settings: View {
    let auth: UserAuth
    init(auth: UserAuth) {
        self.auth = auth
    }
    @State var minAge = UserSettings().minAge
    let settings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                NavigationView {
                    Form {
                        Section {
                        Text("Min age")
                        Slider(value: $minAge, in: 18...99, step: 1, label: {Text("Label")})
                            .onReceive([self.minAge].publisher.first()) { (value) in
                                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.minAge, forKey: "minAge")
                            }
                        Text(String(Int(minAge)))
                        }
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: This seems a slight catch-all error: I've also had it when declaring an optional property with an initial value (Bool? = true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need intermediate state and `UserDefaults`, because you can bind directly to `AppStorage` value and it is by default uses `UserDefaults.standard`. Also you need to use same types with `Slider` which is `Double`.

So, here is a minimal demo solution. Tested with Xcode 12.

```
struct Settings: View {
    @AppStorage("minAge") var minAge: Double = 18

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Text("Min age")
                        Slider(value: $minAge, in: 18...99, step: 1, label: {Text("Label")})
                        Text(String(Int(minAge)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou this works. How do you know that `Double` is required? Doesn't say in the`Slider` doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/slider

Comment: It's very much implied (Apple binds the slider to a value that's a Double), and when I changed that to Int, my app failed to compile with _Initializer 'init(value:in:onEditingChanged:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'BinaryFloatingPoint'_. This means you can use Double, Float, or CGFloat

Answer (score 5):

I am also seeing the same error with the following:

```
@AppStorage ("FavouriteBouquets") var favouriteBouquets: [String] = []()
```

Perhaps an array of Strings is not supported by AppStorage.

**Edit** Found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602643/87622).

Comment: You can also conform `Array` to `RawRepresentable` like in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563773/8697793

Answer (score 1):

This happens when one of the following conditions is not met:

1. Missing `default value` on initialization:

```
@AppStorage("someKey") var someValue: Double //  Missing default value

@AppStorage("someKey") var someValue: Double? // ✅ the default value will be nil
@AppStorage("someKey") var someValue: Double = 1 // ✅ the default value will be 1.0
```

2. The type of the `Value` is not one of the following types / or does not conform to the `RawRepresentable` where the `RawValue` type is one of the following:

```
✅ where Value == TableColumnCustomization<RowValue>, RowValue : Identifiable

✅ where Value == Bool
✅ where Value == Int
✅ where Value == Double
✅ where Value == String
✅ where Value == URL
✅ where Value == Data
✅ where Value : RawRepresentable, Value.RawValue == Int
✅ where Value : RawRepresentable, Value.RawValue == String

// MARK: - Optional
✅ where Value == Bool?
✅ where Value == Int?
✅ where Value == Double?
✅ where Value == String?
✅ where Value == URL?
✅ where Value == Data?
✅ where Value == R?, R : RawRepresentable, R.RawValue == String
✅ where Value == R?, R : RawRepresentable, R.RawValue == Int
```

So any custom type should conform to RawRepresentable and the RawValue **MUST** be one of the above:

```
class MyType: RawRepresentable { //  Conform to the required protocol

    typealias RawValue = String //  Use one of the accepted types as the `RawValue`

    required init(rawValue: RawValue) {
        self.someValue = Int(rawValue)!
    }

    var rawValue: RawValue { "\(someValue)" }

    // MARK: Class Implementation
    var someValue: Int = 0
}
```

Now this works as expected:

```
@AppStorage("someKey") var someValue = MyType(rawValue: "1") // ✅ the default value of (inner) `someValue` will be 1
```