# How to use @AppStorage for a Dictionary of Strings [String: String]

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, appstorage

Hey in my app I am trying to store whether the User wants a location to be its favourite. In order to make the change in this UserDefaults update the view I need to use @AppStorage. However, at the moment I only get the ERROR "No exact matches in call to initializer" Do i need to use Data instead of the [String: String], if yes how? Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance

```
import SwiftUI

struct SpotDetailView: View {
    @State var spot: WindApp //knows which spot it's at
    var spotname:String
    //@State var favourites: [String:String] = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "heart") as? [String:String] ?? [:]
    @AppStorage("heart") var favourites: [String: String] = [:]

        
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            List {
                SpotMapView(coordinate: spot.locationCoordinate)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                ForEach(0..<9) { i in
                    SingleDayView(spot: spot, counter: (i * 8))
                    }
            }
            .navigationTitle("\(spot.spot)")
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        if favourites[spot.spot] == "heart" {
                            favourites[spot.spot] = "heart.fill"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(favourites, forKey: "heart")
                        }
                        else if favourites[spot.spot] == "heart.fill" {
                            favourites[spot.spot] = "heart"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(favourites, forKey: "heart")
                        }
                        else {
                            favourites[spot.spot] = "heart.fill"
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(favourites, forKey: "heart")
                        }
                
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: favourites[spot.spot] ?? "heart")
                    })
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using @AppStorage for string map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602279/using-appstorage-for-string-map)

Answer (score 6):

You can make Dictionary [String:String] conform to RawRepresentable.

```swift
extension Dictionary: RawRepresentable where Key == String, Value == String {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),  // convert from String to Data
            let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),   // data is  Data type
              let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) // coerce NSData to String
        else {
            return "{}"  // empty Dictionary resprenseted as String
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks great, what would I need to modify to get this set up for [String : Bool]?

Comment: @NathanaelTse : I think you only need to replace in the first line `where Key == String, Value == String` with `where Key == String, Value == Bool` and in line 4 : `.decode([String:String]`with `.decode([String:Bool]`

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use Data. @AppStorage currently only supports:

- Int
- Double
- String
- Bool
- URL
- Data

See this answer for [sample implementation and further details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602643/15232168)

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend storing your [String: String] object as Data.

Since [String: String] conforms to Codable out of the box this is an easy task.

This is an example of how you could implement it and also get Combine support.
Notice that `MyUserDefaultsStorage` is not only for this value but you can add additional values you would like to store in `AppStorage`.

```
struct MyUserDefaultsStorage {

    var favorites: CurrentValueSubject<[String: String], Never> = .init([:])

    @AppStorage("stars")
    private var favoritesData = Data()

    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    private let encoder = JSONEncoder()

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        do {
            favorites.value = try decoder.decode([String: String].self, from: favoritesData)
        } catch {
            print("No saved data")
        }

        favorites
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .encode(encoder: encoder)
            .replaceError(with: Data())
            .assign(to: \.favoritesData, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```