# @AppStorage: Picker not responding

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

In the following code, I have a `Picker` bound to `array`, which is an `@AppStorage` variable.

The issue is that the picker never shows "value2" as the selected item, even though it's being set in the `.onAppear` method. Why isn't this working?

Debugging shows that the `.onAppear` is working, and that array["item1"] has a value of `Optional("value2")` despite the `Picker` not showing these changes. I assume it has to do with the optional value, but I'm not sure how.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("array") var array: [String : String] = ["item1":"value1"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker("", selection: $array["item1"]) {
            Text("value1").tag("value1")
            Text("value2").tag("value2")
            Text("value3").tag("value3")
        }
        .onAppear {
            array["item1"] = "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

Note I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842479/14063245) extension to save dictionaries in `@AppStorage` in XCode 15 beta 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is in the debugging you mentioned. The type is an `Optional` and your `Picker` `tag` must match the type *exactly*. `String != Optional(String)`

```
Picker("", selection: $array["item1"]) {
    Text("value1").tag(Optional("value1"))
    Text("value2").tag(Optional("value2"))
    Text("value3").tag(Optional("value3"))
}
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. Why doesn't `$array["item1"]!` work? It throws an error, but why can't we unwrap the `selection` instead of casting the `.tag` as optional?

Comment: I think if it were just `array["item1"]` you might be okay with that, but the `$` adds a wrinkle -- it's probably the `Binding` that creates that is getting in the way. You could create a custom `Binding` that returns a non-Optional.