# Is there a way to implement @AppStorage on a custom property wrapper?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to use `@AppStorage` on custom property wrapper like this:

`@AppStorage("imports") var name: [NameSection]`

My app works normal without the `@AppStorage("imports")`.

I keep getting this "*No exact matches in call to initializer*" error when add the `@AppStorage`

I know that the error is caused due to not using the Property Wrappers Supported.

I have looked at these links for reference but all these once are using the data types, so none of them helped:
[Using @AppStorage for string map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602279/using-appstorage-for-string-map/62602643#62602643)
['No exact matches in call to initializer' error on @AppStorage variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62810002/no-exact-matches-in-call-to-initializer-error-on-appstorage-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[SwiftUI: What is @AppStorage property wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562534/swiftui-what-is-appstorage-property-wrapper?noredirect=1&lq=1)

All I am trying to do is save the data in AppStorage once its decoded

Here is my decoder for my NameSection:

```
                 VStack (spacing: 30) {
                        Button(action: {imported.toggle()}, label: {
                            Text("Import")
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                        })
                    }
                    .fileImporter(isPresented: $imported, allowedContentTypes: [.json]) { res in
                        do {
                            let fileUrl = try res.get()
                            if fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
                                let fileData = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
                                defer  { fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
                                let importedNames = try? JSONDecoder().decode([NameSection].self, from: fileData)
                                name = importedNames ?? []
                                importDone = true
                            }else{
                                
                            }
                        } catch{
                            print (error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
```

And here is the struct for my NameSection:

```
struct NameSection: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var items: [NameItem]
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}

struct NameItem: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String

    static let example = NameItem(id: UUID(), name: "Geeth Gunnampalli")

    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a default value to your declaration? e.g., `@AppStorage("imports") var name: [NameSection] = []`

Comment: I used it a bit different in one of my applications. I went for something like this; `@Appstorage("imports") var name: Data = Data()` Then I use a `JSONEncoder` to encode my custom struct to a `Data` object. Then whenever I need it, I decode it using a JSONDecoder.

Comment: yeah I tried both none of them work in my case.

Comment: Is this answer of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65598711/372347